# Kotlin: why do I need to initialize a var with custom getter?

Tags: kotlin

Why do I need to initialize a `var` with a custom getter, that returns a constant?

```
var greeting: String // Property must be initialized 
get() = "hello"
```

I don't need initialization when I make `greeting` read-only (`val`)

Comment: Why don't you turn it into `val` then? Every mutable property with a backing field needs to be initialized.

Comment: @miensol Agreed, this should be a `val`. I was confused myself; the source of the confusion was thinking of the `val`/`var` difference as constant vs. variable, rather than read-only vs. mutable.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Reason behind this is [Backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields). When you create val with custom getter that does not use field identifier to access its value, then backing field is not generated.

```
val greeting: String
    get() = "hello"
```

If you do, then backing field is generated and needs to be initialized.

```
val greeting: String // Property must be initialized
    get() = field
```

Now with var. Since backing filed is generated by default, it must be initialized.

```
var greeting: String // Property must be initialized
    get() = "hello"
```

For this to work for var without initialization, you must provide a custom setter to prevent generation of backing field. For example:

```
var storage: String = ""
var greeting: String
    get() = "hello"
    set(value) { storage = value}
```

Comment: What is mean by initialization? provide the setter? or provider the value during declaration? can you confirm please?

Comment: Providing a value. Either by explicit initializer or inside the init block.

Comment: if I didn't provide any value either during declaration or init block. Why it required to write both getter and setter? I mean suppose I just write set block as it.     `var good : Int
        set(value){
            field = 3
        }` it will still show error about initialization. But once I write `get() = 3` or something it will solve the error. What is the reason behind?

Comment: `var good : Int
        set(value){
            field = 3
        }
        get() = 3` it is not working Don't know why. but when I remove `field=3` it works fine initialization error gone.

Comment: Same as in the answer above. Take a look at the link to the backing field documentation. Var generates backing field if you are using default get/set or if you reference field in your custom ones. Ad if backing field gets generated it needs to be initialized.

Comment: I already read the documents but was confused about the initialization. So just to confirm the initialization mean assigning the value during declaration or from the constructor? because I'm also initializing here. `var good : Int set(value){ field = 3 } get() = 3` but it is not working.

Comment: Correct. Either explicit initializer or init. Code you posted is not initialization. get/set are just custom accessors. You modified set to always set good to 3 and get to always return 3.

Answer (score 18):

Your code does not have a custom setter, so it is equivalent to:

```
var greeting: String
    get() = "hello"
    set(v) {field = v}  // Generated by default
```

The default implementation of `set` uses `field`, so you've got to initialise it.

By the same logic, you don't have to init the field if nether your `set` nor `get` use it (which means they are both custom):

```
var greeting: String  // no `field` associated!
    get() = "hello"
    set(v) = TODO()
```

Comment: If you don't need the setter, it should be a `val` property.

Comment: If you are getting this error with both `get` and `set` defined, make sure you are not using the `field` reference in any of these functions (like the setter in the example above). Removing the `field` from the implementations will remove the error.