# "Property must be initialized or be abstract" in init block when throwing an exception

Tags: kotlin

Why does kotlin report `Property must be initialized or be abstract`. The object construction is never finished, so it should not matter whether `a` is initialized or not. Could a case be demonstrated where this would be a problem?

```
class Foo {
    private val a: Int

    init {
        a = 42
        throw Exception()
    }
}

fun main() {
    Foo()
}
```

[kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/svJbpfD6A)

---

However these work just fine

```
fun bar() {
    throw Exception()
}

class Foo {
    private val a: Int

    init {
        a = 42
        bar()
    }
}

fun main() {
    Foo()
}
```

[kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/sC6MP3Xq8)

```
class Foo {
    private val a: Int = throw Exception()
}

fun main() {
    Foo()
}
```

[kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/RLBeoEZjX)

---

Similar java code works as expected:

```java
public class Test {
    private static class Foo {
        private final int a;

        public Foo() throws Exception {
            a = 42;
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

     public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
         new Foo();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a compiler bug as Alexey suggested
There is [similar issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30085) posted on Kotlin bug tracer.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very well answered in the below link.
[Kotlin: why do I need to initialize a var with custom getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440750/kotlin-why-do-i-need-to-initialize-a-var-with-custom-getter)

Essentially it boils down to having a backing field for every "val" (property) . If you can provide a backing field, you need not initialize the field. Below is a small example of it.

```
class Foo {
    private val a: Int
    get() = getValue()

}

fun getValue():Int {
    throw Exception()
}

fun main() {
    Foo()
}
```

Comment: "If you can provide a backing field, you need not initialize the field." It's the opposite. If a property has a backing field, it needs to be initialized; if it doesn't, there's nothing to initialize.

Comment: I don't think it is about backing fields. I added a second example which is pretty much identical to the problematic code, yet it works.

Answer (score 1):

> Similar java code works as expected:

Java initializes fields to 0 (or `null`/`false` depending on type) by default. You can see it e.g. by printing `a`'s value before the `a = 42` line.

Kotlin doesn't, because this implicit initialization makes it too easy to forget to initialize a property and doesn't provide much benefit. So it requires you to initialize all properties which have backing fields.

Comment: Java requires fields to be initialized, just as Kotlin does. However the value before initialization may be different, but I don't see how it relates to this case.

Comment: @Watu Yes, since the example in https://pl.kotl.in/sC6MP3Xq8 compiles (and so does `if (true) { throw Exception() }`), this isn't the problem. May just be a compiler bug.