# what is the difference between var and val in extension properties?

Tags: kotlin

I created extension properties and I'm having this problem

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(Animal("Mia",1,1.0))
}

class Animal(var name : String, var age : Int, var weight : Double)

var Animal.getXXX : String   // compiler : Property must be initialized
get() = "$name, $age, $weight"

val Animal.getXXX : String   // the compiler is running properly
get() = "$name, $age, $weight"
```

in the code above. why should i use `val` instead of `var`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin: why do I need to initialize a var with custom getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440750/kotlin-why-do-i-need-to-initialize-a-var-with-custom-getter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is perhaps a bit confusing. For extension fields using `var` they are expected to have both a getter and a setter. Fields using `val` only need to have a getter (and can't have a setter). The following code works:

```
var Animal.getFoo : String
get() = "$name, $age, $weight"
set(value) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

var is mutable and we can reassign or change its value. But we can't change val value.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `var` and `val` in extension properties is that while writing extension property if you use `val` you can only use get because you can not set value to it as it is immutable constant variable you can not use set() in val extension property

For Example

```
val String.extensionProperty
    get() = "Value"
```

And if you want to make an extension property with `var` which you want to be mutable so you can set value into it as well and perform any other action while updating varaible.

For Example

```
var String.extensionProperty
    get() = "Value"
    set(value) {
        println("variable has been updated with this data $value")
    }
```